# Disjoint Collection Method in Apex?

Tags: apex

Does the disjoint method (mentioned in the Java documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#disjoint%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection%29) exist in Apex? To summarize the method takes two Lists/Sets and compares them to see if either contains an element in the other and returns true if they do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't appear to be provided as a method, but you can easily do that using the tools Salesforce does provide us.

```
Set<Integer> set1 = new Set<Integer>{1, 2, 3};
Set<Integer> set2 = new Set<Integer>{1, 2};
Set<Integer> set3 = new Set<Integer>{4, 5, 6};

set1.retainAll(set2);         // Should result in {1, 2}
System.debug(set1.isEmpty()); // False, not disjoint, because both sets contained {1, 2}

set1.retainAll(set3);         // Should result in an empty set
System.debug(set1.isEmpty()); // True, is disjoint
```

Comment: Good work around and cleaner than what i came up with but wish it didn't mutate the original set (though as Charles did below, cloning is certainly an option)

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can hack it out of methods that do exist.

Given `set1` and `set2`:

```
Set<T> tempSet = set1.clone();
tempSet.retainAll(set2);
Boolean containsAny = tempSet.isEmpty();
```

Create a temporary copy of `set1`, retain only items in `set2`, and it's either empty or not.

EDIT: Thanks for Derek F's correction.

Comment: Close, but we can't chain those particular methods. `retainAll()` and `removeAll()` return `Boolean` instead of a set.

Comment: oops, fair point!

Comment: (It's kind of awful that the available methods all mutate the Set rather than return a new one)